# How to set opacity ONLY to the background

Tags: html, css

I have an issue here, I am trying to use a HTML5 select element, I need to set this element to be transparent, but once I put the opacity property, then the letters/content of the select element becomes transparent, like this

[image]

so all I need is to set that element's background transparent, is there a way to do that, or I need to set the background color of the element as the same blue color on the background of that picture ?

```
  select {
    background-color: get-color(nieve);
    border: 2px solid get-color(golden-poppy);
    border-top: 0;
    color: get-color(night);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
```

Comment: Can you share a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the background color with `rgba()`

```
element{
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

The first three values are the RGB levels, and the last one is the opacity (in this case 50% opaque, the higher the number the less transparent)

Comment: Except if I already have background color defined using `var()` and only need to apply opacity change.

Answer (score 1):

You can set background-color using [rgba ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba())

```
select {
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, .4);
    border: 2px solid get-color(golden-poppy);
    border-top: 0;
    color: get-color(night);
}
```